# Spring Boot, Elasticsearch 6.2.4, Gradle dependency issues

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am converting a legacy application to Spring Boot. This application currently uses Elasticsearch 6.2.4

When creating the following dependencies in my `build.gradle` file, it includes the wrong version of Elasticsearch, 5.6.11:

```
dependencies {
    // Spring Boot Starters
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'

    // Elasticsearch
    compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.2.4'
}
```

Output from `./gradlew dependencies`

```
+--- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.2.4
|    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.2.4 -> 5.6.11
```

I am assuming this is some magic happening due to the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin.

How can I override this behavior and still use my explicit configured version while converting this legacy application to Spring Boot?

**Note that I am not using `spring-data` at the moment, nor do I have plans to move to that anytime soon. My current application manages the ES client and all interactions itself without any Spring abstraction layer.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ext {
    set('elasticsearch.version', '6.2.4')
}
```

[Blogpost about overriding versions](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot)

Comment: Thanks Vlad! That seems to do the trick. Although I cannot find your solution anywere in the Blogpost you linked. I'd love to understand how it works and any potential issues this approach could have.

Comment: Here is another link that explains ways to override versions when dependency-management-plugin is used: https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/#dependency-management-configuration-bom-import-override

Comment: This not going to work, despite official documentation of spring gradle depedency managment tool assures it does. Using version property will lead to 
+--- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -> 5.6.11

use concrete version in dependency section in build gradle 
compile ('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.2.4')
will improve result but with no luck
 +--- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.8.0 -> 7.6.2

Only trick is to use with *set*.

Answer (score 2):

While searching answer for same I came across following soln:

```
ext['elasticsearch.version'] = '6.2.4'
```

[Reference Doc section 3.1 Customizing managed versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation)

These versions are picked BOM file available at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

The different release would have a different set of versions in the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the future reference. The version added in ext can be referenced in dependency using property() so that we don't need to duplicate version declaration.

```
compile ("org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:${property('elasticsearch.version')}")
```

Comment: Same as next comment, this is not going to work at all.